# AWS s3 expressJS image upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I am using AWS s3 in order to upload and retrieve images for posts that contain images and form data.
After setting up AWS s3 I received this error:

```
throw new Error("No value provided for input HTTP label: " + memberName + ".");
              ^

Error: No value provided for input HTTP label: Key.
    at resolvedPath (C:\Users\David\OneDrive\Desktop\dealership-comission-2\server\node_modules\@smithy\smithy-client\dist-cjs\resolve-path.js:19:15)
    at se_PutObjectCommand (C:\Users\David\OneDrive\Desktop\dealership-comission-2\server\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-s3\dist-cjs\protocols\Aws_restXml.js:2453:53)
    at async C:\Users\David\OneDrive\Desktop\dealership-comission-2\server\node_modules\@smithy\middleware-serde\dist-cjs\serializerMiddleware.js:12:21
```

I have tried looking at different forums and videos and this is the code I have for the AWS S3 setup:

```
const { S3Client, PutObjectCommand, GetObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const { getSignedUrl } = require("@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner");

const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

const bucketName = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME;
const region = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION;
const accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
const secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;

const s3Client = new S3Client({
  region,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey
  }
});

function uploadFile(fileBuffer, fileName, mimetype) {
  const uploadParams = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Body: fileBuffer,
    Key: fileName,
    ContentType: mimetype
  };

  return s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams));
}

async function getObjectSignedUrl(key) {
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: key
  };

  const command = new GetObjectCommand(params);
  const seconds = 60;
  const url = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, { expiresIn: seconds });

  return url;
}

module.exports = {
  uploadFile,
  getObjectSignedUrl
};
```

Comment: Is the value for `Key` being set in both functions? Print them out and verify that they are actually being set.